# What are some other services like Open DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, opendns

First of all, what's the term for services like Open DNS? Public DNS servers?

I like how Open DNS allows content filtering and statistics monitoring. But I just wanted to get an idea of what else was out there that gives similar functionality. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would call them free DNS resolution services.

The only other I know of similar to OpenDNS is [DNS Advantage](http://www.dnsadvantage.com/dnsadv/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Google runs what are probably the most popular at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 but you can find a list at http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/free-public-dns-servers.htm

that is if resolution is all you want.